# Export Query Layer does not return all values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, export, arcgis-10.4, query

When I create a query layer, the attribute table has 1004 records. When I attempt to export this data to a file geodatabase, it only has 523 records. I have tried exporting to a personal geodatabase, a shapefile, and also using Copy Features to export the data, each time only 523 records are exported.

What is going on?

When exporting to a geodatabase or using copy features tool, there is no error message. Only when I export to a shapefile, do I get three separate pop up windows:

1. Error exporting data
   Error reading some rows from the source. These rows have not been converted.
2. Warning: Some records may not have been exported correctly.
3. There was an error exporting the layer.

I have managed to export many features successfully, but there appears to be a few tables that struggle with this.

I'm new to this type of work.

As a note, there are no joins or selections on the query layer when I attempt to perform the export. I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.5686, Advanced License.

Comment: Have you tried running a repair geometry on a copy of your layer?

Comment: Hi Johns, thank you for your question. I have not tried doing this because I must export it to the geodatabase first in order to do so. By the time the layer is exported to the geodatabase, those features have been removed.

Comment: Where is the data stored that you are creating this query layer on?

Comment: An oracle database.

Comment: What happens when you try to Copy Features from your feature class stored in Oracle to a new feature class stored in Oracle.  Don't forget to use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Have you examined in detail one feature that goes missing during your export?  Is it tiny, does it self-intersect, etc?